# Have a mutable sequence or always delete and create a new immutable sequence?

Tags: performance, scala, immutability

I have an IndexedSeq that I will read some stuff from then update it and loop.

Which is more efficient:

- Have one mutable IndexedSeq and update it and read from it
- Every time I want to update, delete it and construct a new immutable IndexedSeq

So, Scala defaults to immutable (second method). Isn't it inefficient having to delete and allocate again and again for a million time every 3 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

Given how you posed the question, I strongly suspect that you already know the answer (for some cases).

However, which is more dangerous?

- Have one mutable IndexedSeq accessed by all sorts of different methods
- Make each method create a new internally-consistent IndexedSeq if that method needs to change it

The nice thing about immutability is that it's easy to reason about, not that it's fast.  That said, various tree structures can get you back into O(log n) territory for operations you might fear are O(n); sometimes even O(1) is possible by cleverly choosing the data structure.

In particular, Scala's `Vector` is the default `IndexedSeq`, and it has an `updated` method that only does `O(log n)` work, with a base on the logarithm of 32.  It's certainly nowhere near as fast as updating an array; depending on details it might even be 100x slower.  But *most* of the time you don't actually need something 100x faster, you need something that isn't broken.

The trick is in knowing your requirements and using the appropriate language constructs in the appropriate places.

Comment: hmm... in my case I don't see any benefits of having immutable structures, so I think I should go with the mutable one (apparently it is an ArrayBuffer internally). I'm coming from a C# background, so I'm still figuring out how I can take advantage of Scala's features. I feel like I'm bending it to accommodate my old ways of doing things.

Comment: As the saying goes " I can write code that runs as fast as you like, if it doesn't have to be correct" (attributed to Jon Bentley, I think). If you aren't convinced that the easier reasoning about immutable structures will make it more likely your program is correct, then no, you'll see no value from immutability. Another quote (from Tony Hoare) "There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies, and the other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies." Immutability helps with the former.